# Select table row and check checkbox using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table and I want to select the rows that satisfy my criteria and check their respective checkbox. Let's say I want to get the rows with date `2013-03-21`. How can I do this using JQuery?

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        Record1
    </td>
    <td>
        2013-03-21
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Record2
    </td>
    <td>
        2013-03-22 
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Record3
    </td>
    <td>
        2013-03-21
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve **your** task **yourself**? If yes - how? And what have you failed at?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("table tr").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().trim() == '2013-03-21') {
     $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", true);
  }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Fdhyp/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), You better assign some id to table and use that in selector and be sepecific

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xf9rm/1/)**

```
trs = $('td').filter(function(){
 if($.trim($(this).text()) == '2013-03-21')
    return $(this).parent();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you cam use `filter`:

```
var tableRow = $("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == '2013-03-21';
}).closest("tr");
```

or use `contain`:

```
var tableRow = $("tr:has(td:contains('2013-03-21'))");
```