# Javascript check boxes based on text in rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert this: [Select table row and check checkbox using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633471/select-table-row-and-check-checkbox-using-jquery)

into normal javascript, since I'm in a situation where I cannot use jquery.

Here is the orignal

```
    $("table tr").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().trim() == '2013-03-21') {
     $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", true);
  }
});
```

This is what I have so far, and I'm sure its way off:

```
var elements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("table tr"));

Array.prototype.forEach(elements, function(){
var tdText = this.querySelectorAll("td").textContent
if (tdText == '2013-03-21') {
     this.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").setAttribute("checked", true);
  }
});
```

This is the original table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Record1</td>
        <td>2013-03-21</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Record2</td>
        <td>2013-03-22</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Record3</td>
        <td>2013-03-21</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a nodeList of elements.

You need to iterate those and deal with each instance or use the index you want like:

```
element.querySelectorAll("td")[0]
```

Comment: I could just pull the text from the second td. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fdhyp/158/ still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The code `var tdText = this.querySelectorAll("td").textContent` will return an undefined textContent because you are referring to the `tr`'s `NodeList`. You can loop through it and then you can get the `td`'s content:

```
let rows = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('table tr'));
let textDate = '2013-03-21';

rows.map((row) => {
    let cells = Array.prototype.slice.call(row.querySelectorAll('td'));
    for (let i = 0, length = cells.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (cells[i].textContent === textDate) {
            let cb = row.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
            cb[0].checked = true;
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use `ElemCollection.forEach.call` instead of using `Array#slice.call` as `HTMLCollection` does not have `forEach` method
- Use `[1]` index while selecting text from `td` element
- `this` in `Array#forEach` does not refer to `element`, use `first` argument of `Array#forEach` callback function which is `item` of `array`

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("table tr"), function(elem) {
  var tdText = elem.querySelectorAll("td")[1].textContent;
  if (tdText === '2013-03-21') {
    elem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").setAttribute("checked", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Record1</td>
    <td>2013-03-21</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Record2</td>
    <td>2013-03-22</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Record3</td>
    <td>2013-03-21</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```